# How to save a File in GlassFish server

Tags: java, glassfish, oracle-adf

I develop ADF fusion apllication and 
I want to save a file in the glassfish 4.1 server in the following path in a file upload

"C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\"+fileName

Ex -

```
String path = "C://glassfish4//glassfish//domains//domain1//"+ Filename;
File f = new File(path);
f.createNewFile();
```

But I found that the file is not saved in the path after the execution of the code. This works on weblogic but does not work in glassfish

Any idea to save a file in the above path in GlassFish 4.1

Thanks

Comment: Hi, your code (if it is the one), does not create an actual file. It creates a file object. add f.createNewFile() to have the file created.

Comment: Thanks nomadus, I edited the question, problem as above, any idea to fix this

Comment: what is pth variable?

Comment: Sorry, small mistake. That is path.

Comment: Could you please quick check what is the result of this f.createNewFile() line?

Comment: It gives True as the results, This works in weblogic but the same code does not create a file in the specified folder in glassFish

Comment: I guess it is deleted immediately after creation

Comment: Can you create a file in Windows Explorer in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, can create

Comment: But is it stays there? Is it deleted after some time?

Comment: No, that stays, I want to know is there any error in the code above

Comment: No, I don't see any errors with your code. Although, you could use more later method, such as nio2